# Remove ramp from z+1 layer

Tags: dwarf-fortress

**EDIT** See my comment below, this question is solved. HOWEVER, please do read, as the reason I use this (cart-only entrance), doesn't seem to work. That is, I have the construction as defined in the image below (except for a ramp on `z-1, x2, y0`, with a floor above it), but using `D` to show trader routes, still shows the path as inaccessible. Any thoughts on this?

Can anyone explain to me how I can create the following picture (as shown on the [DF Wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Wagon#Wagon-only_entrances)):

```
z = -1  z = 0
▓▓▓▓▓  ▓+++▓ 
▓+++▓  ▓+++▓  
▓▲▲▲▓  ▓▼▼▼▓  
▓+++▓  ▓+++▓  
▓▓▓▓▓  ▓+++▓
```

I am having troubles removing all but the middle ramps in the `Z -1` layer, without getting any dwarfs trapped.

What I currently have:

```
z = -1  z = 0
▓▓▓▓▓  ▓+++▓ 
▓+▲+▓  ▓+▼+▓  
▓▲▲▲▓  ▓▼▼▼▓  
▓+++▓  ▓+++▓  
▓▓▓▓▓  ▓+++▓
```

What I tried (`0,0` = top left):

- build floor at `z0`, `x2`, `y1`, remove floor, ramp still there
- Channel `z-1, x2, y1`, build floor at `z0, x2, y0+1`, remove floor at `z0, x2, y0`, floor at `z0, x2, y1` now collapses on ramp, but ramp still there.

I'd like to do it within the confines of the above axises, and I can't use `z1` due to being close to other caves.

The ramp is natural (well, by Channeling), not by building a ramp manually.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I posted this, I re-read the [thread that discussed this technique](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=60305.0), and it turns out you need a **constructed** ramp, for it to cave-in. This worked.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is exactly what this design is supposed to make happen. The bottom 3x3 area is supposed to be inaccessible to anything except mystical wagons, so if your dwarf is down there, there's no way out. To fix it:

Go to your `z-1` layer, remove the northern ramp, so the `z-1` looks like this:

```
z = -1 
▓▓▓▓▓  
▓+++▓  
▓▲▲▲▓  
▓+++▓   
▓▓▓▓▓
```

For any ramps that disappear during the building/deconstruction/remove-ramps section, rebuild them as a construction.

Now dig (using the dwarf who removed the ramp) an escape path, then wall it in behind you. I'd recommend heading out the north or south way, as if you go out directly east or west it might remove the left or right ramp.

For future attempts at this design, I'd work with these steps.

1. Given a north-south 3-wide corridor
2. Dig a channel (`d-h`) 3-wide across the corridor
3. When that's done: dig two 3-wide channels north and south of the first one

   - The delay is to avoid an accidental cave-in if the center of the 3x3 is the last thing standing
4. In the `z-1` layer build a ramp (`b-C-r`) in the center of the 3x3 dug-out area below
5. Remove the 6 ramps (`d-z`) on north and south walls of the `z-1` layer
6. You're done. Let your sacrificial dwarf starve and die down there

   - Or, dig him an escape route out (anywhere other than the center east/west walls) and build a wall behind him

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this answer as correct. However, even with this design, the carts still pass along, mentioning I have no accessible trade depot (which I had, before I dug out this thing). Just to be clear, in my above picture (and yours), the carts come in from the north or south, right? Not sure why it's not working for me.